# Always show scrollbars for PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, scrollbars, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I have defined preferences in my app using preferences.xml and a PreferenceActivity. The settings are presented in the phone in a ScrollView-like-way. I would like to always show the vertical scrollbars all the time. In Android 1.6 they do not fade away, but in Android 2.2 the fade away after about a second. In a ScrollView I can control this using android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack or android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade. How can I do this with the preference widget?

/P

Answer (score 2):

This worked for my Android 2.3.3 .

```
public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the above suggestions didn't work for me when I wanted to do this for a TextView:

```
TextView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"` in the `PreferenceScreen`.

Comment: If you mean like this: <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"> is does not work.

Answer (score 0):

So hey, this is a seriously ugly solution, but its short and it works.

```
public class PreferenceActivity extends Activity {
//Sorry for stupid variable names, couldn't be bothered to be smart
    private ScrollView svOptions;
    private Runnable _run_sb_on;
    private final Handler _handle_sb_on = new Handler(); 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preference);

        svOptions = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svOptions);
        _run_sb_on = new Runnable() { //i hate you google for making me write crap code ! 
            public void run() {
                svOptions.fling(0); //don't move it, just keep it alive
                _handle_sb_on.postDelayed(this, 300); //300 is the timeout of the fader 
            }
        }; 
        _handle_sb_on.post(_run_sb_on);
    }

    //  etc

}
```

So there you have it.  Note that the fling can eat on-touch events, its rare but its a little annoying - but workable.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the scroller that you want to show scrollbars all the time:

```
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
```

Counterintuitive, I know, but it works perfectly.

Comment: Oops, sorry, noticed that you are talking about preferences.xml. This approach isn't likely to work in this instance.